# Excel VBA Clear Contents from two rows if a third one is deleted

Tags: excel, vba

Need some help with a little code.

I have created the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

    ThisRow = Target.Row
    If Target.Column = 5 Then
        Range("C" & ThisRow).Value = Format(DateTime.Now, "hh:mm")
        Range("D" & ThisRow).Value = Format(DateTime.Now, "mm/dd/yyyy")
        Range("C:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End If

End Sub
```

Basically, if I entered information on any cell on column E, code will display "Time" in the same row on column C and "Date" on the same row on column D.

This is working fine. However, I would like to have this code deleting the information on columns C and D if the entry on columns E gets deleted and the cell is empty.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

    Dim ThisRow As Long

    ThisRow = Target.Row

    If Target.Column = 5 Then
        ' if current Cell in Column E is empty, clear contents
        If Range("E" & ThisRow).Value = "" Then
            Range("C" & ThisRow).ClearContents
            Range("D" & ThisRow).ClearContents
        Else
            Range("C" & ThisRow).Value = Format(DateTime.Now, "hh:mm")
            Range("D" & ThisRow).Value = Format(DateTime.Now, "mm/dd/yyyy")
        End If

        Range("C:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End If

End Sub
```